# How to download unirest post call response in java?

Tags: java, api, unirest

```java
String jsonBody = "<Json input>";
HttpResponse<String> response = null;
        RequestBodyEntity res=null;
        String url = "<some url>";
        try {
            response = Unirest.post(url).header("content-type", "application/json").body(jsonBody).asString();
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.getBody());
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            Reporter.reportStatus("Fail", "Failure in Unirest call", "path is "+url);
        }
        File file = new File("<Location of the file>");
        InputStream input = response.getRawBody();
        try {
            FileOutputStream report = convertInputStreamToFile(input, file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I want to get some response to this post call that will be stored in "response".
I want to download the response, preferably to an excelsheet.
How do I go about it?

Comment: what the issue in your code ? method `convertInputStreamToFile` didn't work?

Comment: The issue is that I am not able to download the response. I need it downloaded as an excel sheet in my local system.